# can we use MySQL for a large data reporting application?

Tags: mysql, linux

We are working on a web application with a big database, that's growing exponentially.

Since we start the dev 4 years ago, it is difficult to change the database to a new architecture, actually we are using a Mysql with Master/Slave configuration on AWS EC2.

Recently we built a reporting suite app for our clients based on the Master/slave configuration, here is

our approach:

```
   Main App
      |
    Master  <=>  Slave
                   |
             Stored procedure  =>  | Database_client_1 
                                   | Database_client_2
                                   | Database_client_3
                                   | Database_client_n
```

Our database have a complicated schema, so EVEN with this solution some queries still take more than 10s.

What do you think about this configuration with (Mysql, Master/slave) for a Large application? and what do you suggest to use as a database for the reporting suite application specially the database will be also used for BI analytics.

Comment: How large is large? What execution time is acceptable? Usually reporting does not require subsecond response times...

Comment: Today we have a few millions, but after going live with our clients we will be playing around with more than millions, the acceptable is 2s.

most of our queries  have a lot of count, like and Join with formatting the output

Comment: One option that you may want to try is using Sphinx http://www.sphinxsearch.com

Comment: Thanks Mark for sharing this option, but how sphinxs could help me in my situation ?